# Why all the dynamically created radio buttons are checked by default in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to create radio buttons for a specific values passed from an API as a JSON object. I have implemented it as follows

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
     <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.type}}</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from "@modules/auth/services/dashboard.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'sb-dashboard-items',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-items.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    items : String;

  constructor(
     private dashboardService : DashboardService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dashboardService.getItems()
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.items = response
        })

  }
}
```

When I run the code, it will generate 3 radio buttons and my issue is all the radio buttons are checked by default. I want to uncheck all the radio buttons by default.

Screenshot of the issue :-
[image]

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to define **value** attribute with **mat-radio-button** and then **ngModel** with **mat-radio-group** to get the selected value.

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" 
                [(ngModel)]="selectedType">                // this line is added

     <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let item of items" 
                [value]="item.type">                      // this line is added
                {{item.type}}
     </mat-radio-button>

</mat-radio-group>
```

**.ts**

```
selectedType:string;
```